# How to paginate a large query correctly with PDO to avoid "out of memory" errors?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, pagination, large-data

I have a very large table which I want to process row by row in PHP.

Here is what I have tried:

- `PDO::fetchAll()`

  Loads all rows in memory immediately: out of memory error.
- Paginating with `PDO::fetchAll()` and `LIMIT X, 1000` (i.e. splitting the large query in smaller ones)

  I was surprised to see that the memory usage kept growing continuously until *out of memory* (at least until 1Gb). Why is the memory not released between queries?

  I have no global variables, no class/object properties, the pagination is encapsulated in a method so the local variables (rows fetched from db) should be collected by the garbage collector once the current page has been processed… I also do not store the rows in memory, I write it to disk.

  Also the bad thing with this technique is that it results in several queries instead of one, which are slow on the very large table.
- `PDO::fetchAll()` with [**buffered queries**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php)

  ```
  $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, true);
  ```

  Finally the memory usage stays very low (~13Mb) but the process is very slow as each row means a network access to the MySQL server.

So my questions:

- why does the pagination method grows out of memory? is there a solution to that?
- is there a way to use buffered queries by batch? (e.g. buffer 1000 rows in memory to avoid network round trips for every row)

Or do you see another better solution?

Comment: It might help if you described what sort of data you are calling (a rough idea of a table, the query) and what you are doing with it in php because currently your problem could be anything.

Comment: @Lucas Take any table with a few columns, put 1M rows in there, and try to iterate over every row in PHP. That's what I'm trying to do. More specifically I want to dump it to CSV (but yes I want specifically to do it in PHP).

Comment: I can still only offer a guess, though from what it sounds like, php may not be the ideal tool for this job. If you are aiming to output into csv, you can SELECT * FROM table INTO OUTFILE '/path/here', if you are wanting to aggregate rows, I'd also do it in SQL.

Comment: Ahh I was expecting that one. You are of course correct, but I want to learn the correct way to iterate over an infinite number of MySQL rows in PHP. It has to be possible surely right?

Comment: And also OUTFILE exports in a file on the mysql server, which isn't possible for me. But even just to learn, I want to know! ;)

Comment: What is your desired end result? Are you trying to write a csv to a seperate computer?

Comment: @Lucas let's say I want to echo every row if that helps…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably I don't understand your question... But, i created simple script that iterates all values from table with ~ `5,436,226` rows (and `19` columns), and save it into out file. I used PostgeSQL instead MySQL (but I do not think that this is a problem, you must change only LIMIT section).

```
<?
ini_set('memory_limit', '100M');

$pdo  = new PDO('pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=test', 'postgres', 'postgres');
$page = 0;
while ($pdo) {
    echo ($page++).PHP_EOL;
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id LIMIT 100 OFFSET '.($page*100));
    $stmt->execute();
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    file_put_contents('/var/www/test/tmp/out.txt', json_encode($rows), FILE_APPEND);
}
```

Out file size is ~1 Gb.

Comment: I think it would be better to put `prepare` before loop and pass paramater to execute

Comment: @Volvox yes, but it does not change the fact that my script does not fall with the memory limit error

Comment: Thank you for the answer, so I guess the conclusion here would be that paginating is a good method and the fact that I'm running out of memory is a bug somewhere in the script? I'm using Zend_Db (which wraps PDO), so maybe the memory leak is in there? I'll try with a simple PDO script like yours.

Comment: Tested locally and indeed the memory usage is stable… So definitely a bug in my script, paginating is definitely OK! Thanks!

Comment: @MatthieuNapoli if don't know how determine memory usage - try https://github.com/phacility/xhprof it show you where is memory lost.

Comment: @stepozer you are right I didn't even think of profiling at that time! I should have done that